# I cant get rspec to work

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

I can't get rspec to work. I did the first level on codeschool, only i followed on my own computer, and it worked fine (had to change should with expect). But now it suddenly stopped doin it thing.

I'm not sure if I did anything to make this happen.

[image: This happens]

I know this probobly isn't sufficient to figure out whats wrong, but do anyone have a clue, or know where I can fix this.

I'm a novice in this so go easy.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a `calc_spec.rb` file in that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rspec is telling you that it can't find the specification file you're trying to run. Can you confirm that `calc_spec.rb` exists in the folder `c:/King Kong/Desktop/the_odin_project/rspec`?

(Please include code/output samples as text, not images, for ease of reference.)

Comment: Yes, it is.
Okay, I think I figured this out. I forgot to put calc.rb in \lib. Is that it?

(Will do with the code/output from now on. Thanks)